# Need shell / perl script to mask sensitive info like first name, dob, ssn etc in a log file on linux

Tags: linux, shell

I need to mask sensitive info like first name, last name, dob, ssn etc in a log file but there is no specific pattern in which they appear. Need to find fields like one below in entire log and mask the info with xxxxx. Please help.

**Log block with sample data**:

```
ghix.log.2014-07-25: INFO 07/25/2014 17:13:14 (PlanDisplayRestClient.java:272) - Fetching  IndividualPlanList : {"inputData":{"household":{"CSR":"CS4","APTC":"187.0"},"issuerVerifiedFlag":true,"totalContribution":null,"enrollmentType":"I","exchangeType":"ON","showCatastrophicPlan":"false","issuerId":null,"groupId":3098,"eligLeadBenefits":",Nutritional counseling,Weight loss programs","subscriberData":null,"planIdStr":"","planType":"Both","tenant":"","providers":[{"id":"18900405","name":"Dr. Rakshit Kumar","networkId":["33602-TXN001","87006-TXN001","91986-TXN001","32600-TXN001","32600-TXN002","355678-FLN001"],"networkTier":"","spciality":"Counseling/Social Work","city":"Austin","state":"TX","providerType":"DOCTOR","networkTierList":null,"networkIdList":["33602-TXN001","87226-TXN001","91716-TXN001","3278-TXN001","32698-TXN002","3545-FLN001"]}],"planLevel":"","isSpecialEnrollment":"NO","pgrmType":"INDIVIDUAL","coverageStartDate":"01/01/2001","insuranceType":"HEALTH","preferences":{"highDrugUseVal":0.0,"lowDrugUseVal":0.0,"moderateMedicalVal":0.0,"highMedicalVal":0.0,"vHighDrugUseVal":0.0,"moderateDrugUseVal":0.0,"vHighMedicalVal":0.0,"lowMedicalVal":0.0}},"groupDataList":[{"groupId":3098,"aptc":187.0,"remainingAptc":0.0,"csr":"CS4","zipcode":"44444","countycode":"45555","personDataList":[{"personId":"1","externalPersonId":null,"existingMedicalEnrollmentID":null,"existingSADPEnrollmentID":null,"firstname":"Primary","lastname":"Tax Filer","dob":"1/1/2001","smoker":"N","dentalEligible":"NO","relationship":"Self","employerContribution":null,"gender":null},{"personId":"2","externalPersonId":null,"existingMedicalEnrollmentID":null,"existingSADPEnrollmentID":null,"firstname":"Primary","lastname":"Tax Filer","dob":"1/1/2001","smoker":"N","dentalEligible":"NO","relationship":"Child","employerContribution":null,"gender":null}]}],"pldHouseholdPersonList":null,"providersList":[{"id":"1000405","name":"Dr. Rakshit Kumar","networkId":["33002-TXN001","87000-TXN001","91000-TXN001","30003-TXN001","32003-TXN002","35000-FLN001"],"networkTier":"","spciality":"Counseling/Social Work","city":"Austin","state":"TX","providerType":"DOCTOR","networkTierList":null,"networkIdList":["33000-TXN001","87200-TXN001","90006-TXN001","30003-TXN001","30003-TXN002","35000-FLN001"]}],"eligLeadId":null,"ssapApplicationId":null,"consumerData":null}
```

**Data to be masked**:

```
"dob":"1/1/2001"
"name":"Dr. Rakshit Kumar"
"smoker":"N"
"dentalEligible":"NO"
```

**Should look like**:

```
"dob":"xxxxx"
"name":"xxxxx"
"smoker":"x"
"dentalEligible":"x"
```

Comment: "need script" - then hire a developer. Stack Overflow users are not here to do your work for free.

Comment: I did not need complete script line by line. You should be able to understand that from my title. I got a direction and thanks to jm666 for that. Even key commands would have helped.

Answer (score 0):

Your log contains valid JSON string. So you need to do:

1. read every line
2. extract JSON from the line
3. read & parse JSON to some internal data structure
4. change the needed fields
5. export the changed data structure to JSON
6. write to masked log to new file
7. done
8. profit

### EDIT

Maybe it can be done from `bash` with some tools, but i'm using for such tasks the Perl language. And it is really offtopic trying teach perl here from zero.

Alternatively, try google for some `manipulating JSON from bash` or such.

for getting the JSON part, you can use something like the next

```
while read -r line
do
    part1=$(sed 's/\(.*IndividualPlanList : \).*/\1/' <<< "$line")
    json=$(sed 's/.*IndividualPlanList : //' <<< "$line")

    #do something with the JSON
    newjson=$(echo "$json")

    #write out the new line
    echo "$part1$newjson"

done < logfile.txt
```

Comment: Thanksa lot jm666. Some key commands for parsing JSON would help as I do not have much hands -on on JSON.

Comment: @user3885546 added some guidelines